# gridview: table-layout: fixed but with different width for columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tablelayout

I hava a gridView with different width of columns (15%,17% ect...).
Some cell contain a very long text- in order to make all text seen and not truncated I used table-layout= fixed in the property "Style" of the gridview.
The problem is- the fixed property makes all columns' width to be equal and not what I defined.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <asp:GridView id="grd" style="width:100%"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please add some details as to what in particular in this code snippet solves the particular problem. You could add that style in css too.